# Two laptops of the same model with two totally different displays?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, colors, calibration

**QUESTIONS**

Why do these two displays look so different? Does this have to do with a Windows setting, or are these actually two different displays installed on the same model of laptop (with no warning from Lenovo)? Could it also be a quality control issue?

[image]

**BACKGROUND**

I recently purchased two laptops (1 silver, 1 dark gray) from Lenovo.com, both of which are a Lenovo Yoga C930 with exactly the same specs: 1TB SSD, 16GB RAM, 13.9" UHD touch display, running the latest version of Windows 10. My plan was to decide which color I wanted and then return the other one. I decided I wanted to keep the silver one but noticed that the quality of the display is drastically different (and inferior) than the display on the gray one. While the silver display gets a little brighter than the gray one, it has an awful blue tint, and the colors are not as bright. The dark gray one is just the better display to look at overall.

**RESEARCH**

I have double-checked to make sure all of the settings are the same on both computers:

- Power cord unplugged
- Brightness set to 100%
- Power mode set to "Best Performance"
- No "night mode", blue light reduction, or any other special display settings turned on

Disclaimer: I am dang-near brand-spanking new to using Windows (have used Mac and Linux almost exclusively for the past 15 years). While I've checked all the settings I can find, I could very-well be missing something.

**OTHER NOTES**

One other thing to note is that I ordered both of these computers within days of each other. The gray one shipped from the Lenovo warehouse right away. The silver one however had to be assembled and shipped from China (due to popular demand during the holidays).

While I'd be totally fine keeping the dark gray one (I've actually grown to like the color a lot more now), there are a couple things holding me back. The first is that the silver one was a lot cheaper (~$350) due to a coupon that wasn't available at the time of purchasing the dark gray one. Also the speakers sound a lot better on the silver one, and the screen wobbles a lot less on the silver one. Another reason why I wonder about quality control.

With all that said, I assure you that Lenovo's website stated that the ONLY difference between these two computers was that one was silver and the other was dark gray.

Comment: What's your Question?  If you could Edit your text (gray 'edit' to the left of your avatar at the bottom of the question) , and just put a question in the first or last sentence, then the community has a way to react to it.

Comment: Thanks. I moved my questions to the top.

Comment: Speculation : The displays look different because they ARE different.  I've seen the same practice done with Black Friday sales.  I don't know if it's legal, but it's definitely not honest.  I'm not making this an Answer because it's speculation and I don't have a good course of action for you.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Actually the dark gray one was a Black Friday deal and the silver one was a Green Monday deal. Green Monday was the better deal for me though. Do you happen to have an example of another company that does this practice? One more interesting thing to note is that the silver one offers the "Lenovo IdeaPad LCD Monitor" color profile and "Windows HD Color", but the dark gray one does not (see picture). I don't know enough about Windows to understand this.

Comment: A lot of companies have some fine print that says "exact specifications may be subject to change" and it may be that between runs of different colours that they had a problem getting their usual LCD panels and did (what they thought) would be a minor substitution. Or you just got the 1 in 1000 poor quality panel.

Comment: Is there anyway to check the model of the panel itself, either with software or by opening up the laptop?